# CupertinoTextFormFieldRow color is white during day and black during evening/night on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

During the evening, the background color of the two CupertinoTextFormFieldRow in my Form (area circled in screenshot below) in my Flutter Cupertino app are black, but during the daytime they are white. I cannot figure out how to change/set the background color for this. Any help is appreciated.

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  late TextEditingController _usernameTextController;
  late TextEditingController _passwordTextController;
  late bool showCircular = false;
  late bool shouldPop = true;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _usernameTextController = TextEditingController();
    _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    showCircular = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool selected = false;

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        _key.currentState!.pop();
        Navigator.of(context).pop();

        return false;
      },
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
          });
        },
        child: CupertinoPageScaffold(
            backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.white,
            child: Stack(children: [
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5.5,
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6.5,
                child: Text(
                  "Login",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: CupertinoColors.black,
                    fontSize: 40,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Positioned(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6.5,
                  right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6.5,
                  child: CupertinoFormSection(
                    backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.white,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    children: [
                      CupertinoTextFormFieldRow(
                        controller: _usernameTextController,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        placeholder: 'Enter email',
                        validator: (email) =>
                            email != null && !EmailValidator.validate(email)
                                ? 'Enter a valid email'
                                : null,
                      ),
                      CupertinoTextFormFieldRow(
                          controller: _passwordTextController,
                          placeholder: 'Enter password',
                          obscureText: true,
                          validator: (password) {
                            if (password == null || password.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Enter a valid password';
                            } else if (password.length < 6) {
                              return 'Must be at least 6 characters long';
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.7,
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6.5,
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6.5,
                child: Container(
                  child: CupertinoButton(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    child: Text(
                      "LOGIN".toUpperCase(),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //PERFORM VALIDATION AND LOGIN
                    }
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.4,
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6.5,
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6.5,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(
                      maintainState: false,
                      builder: (_) => ForgotPassword(),
                    ));
                  },
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'Forgot Password?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.3,
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6.5,
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6.5,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      CupertinoPageRoute(
                        maintainState: false,
                        builder: (_) => CreateAccount(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'Create Account',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  child:
                      showCircular ? CupertinoActivityIndicator() : SizedBox(),
                ),
              ),
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }

  void openDialog() {
    showCupertinoDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
              title: Text('Error'),
              content: Text("Wrong email or password"),
              actions: [
                CupertinoDialogAction(
                    child: Text('OK'), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
              ],
            ));
  }
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: You want to change the color of the _text_?

Comment: Apologies, I was not clear enough. I want to change the color of the background color of the form field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of the *text*, you can use the [`placeholderStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTextField/placeholderStyle.html) property:

```
CupertinoTextFormFieldRow(
      placeholderStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)
```

To change the background color, add a `BoxDecoration()` to the `decoration`:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
```

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe I didn't realise this. I was looking for a color or background color property. I feel pretty stupid I didn't realise I can use decoration....